# Form validation checking for non-numbers

Tags: c#, validation

I am familiar with validation controls in .Net when validating textboxes on my form but not how to do it with C#. I did some research, and I know the basics of validation, like making sure that a control is not null.

But how do you test for characters? I have a textbox ID field that can only be numeric. Nothing I have found from research has used anything like that; it is mostly `IsNullOrEmpty`.

How do you implement something like that to test for a numeric value in a string field?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text))
{
    ValidationMessages.Add("Missing Product Number");
}
```

I solved this below, I needed to compare it to comobox.selectedindex in the if statement.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmboBoxStock.SelectedIndex.ToString()))
{
     rLblStockIDError.Text = "Missing Stock Number";
}
```

Comment: How do you check in C# if a String represents a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the string is a number.

*Using Int32.TryParse*

```
int number;
string value = "123";
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

*Using Double.TryParse*

```
double number;
string value = "123.123";
bool result = Double.TryParse(value, out number)
```

*Your code would be*

```
int number;
if (!Int32.TryParse(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text, out number))
{
    ValidationMessages.Add("Missing Product Number");
```

Comment: I am struggling validating this combobox. I want to make sure the user selected a value and didn't leave it blank. It wont trigger when I leave it blank. Here is what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check for any non numeric characters in the string.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\D");
if (!r.IsMatch(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text))
{
    // The text contains only numeric characters
}
```

\D Matches any character other than a decimal digit.
More about [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

instead of do it at c# code, u can use RegularExpressionValidator,RequiredFieldValidator,regex at the aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNo" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Product Number can only be numeric" ControlToValidate="txtNo" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]$" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="txtNo" errormessage="Missing Product Number" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: I am developing a Winform app not using ASP.Net